# Generate xml fragments from a static set of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a static list of values I want to create a list of XML elements from. The values are: `one`, `two`, and `three`. I'm trying to avoid creating a new table just for this one special use case. The goal is to get rows with the following output from this list:

```
<option value="one"/>
<option value="two"/>
<option value="three"/>
```

I've tried the following SQL query in PostgreSQL which gets close:

```
SELECT xmlelement(name option, xmlattributes(s as value))
FROM (values('one'), ('two')) AS s;
```

However, I end up with the following output:

```
<option value="(one)"/>
<option value="(two)"/>
<option value="(three)"/>
```

I've also tried the following query with the same results:

```
SELECT xmlelement(name option, xmlattributes(s as value))
FROM (SELECT unnest('{one,two}'::varchar[])) AS s;
```

I believe I just need to find a way to refer to that column. I tried using ?column? but it didn't work. I'm also not sure if there is a cleaner way to write what I'm attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it's me but there should be **better ways** of rendering HTML `select` options than database... like i.e. php, ruby, node.js etc.

In any case you can simply do

```sql
SELECT format('<option value="%s"/>', value) AS option
  FROM (VALUES ('one'), ('two'), ('three')) options(value);
```

or

```sql
SELECT xmlelement(name "option", xmlattributes(value AS "value")) AS option
  FROM (VALUES ('one'), ('two'), ('three')) options(value);
```

Output:

```
         option
-------------------------
 <option value="one"/>
 <option value="two"/>
 <option value="three"/>
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d75e8be87e9dc7e8d34e828c05cae719) demo

Comment: I'm working with an existing report generation tool written by someone else, unfortunately, and the best I can do to customize the normal table output is by having the SQL directly generate the HTML I want in place of the normal auto-formatting it generates for a table.